# How to measure centre to centre distance between circles in an image using python

Tags: python

I coded for circle detection in an image using python. I have the centre coordinate of those circle in pixel. But I am not able to measure the centre to centre distance between two circles.

I am using the Hough transformation method to detect circles.

Can anyone please suggest me how should I do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to compute the height and width of a rectangle, that has two non-consecutive corners on the centers of your circles. Then, you can calculate the length of the diagonal of that rectangle using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). I made a little sketch where you can see which variable is which point / distance:

[image]

And here comes the code (I assume you have the centre coordinates of the circles in form of two two-item tuples or lists):

```py
import math

c1 = (20, 40) # replace these with the real values of your circle centers
c2 = (50, 50)

def calculate_diagonal(c1, c2):
    x1, y1 = c1
    x2, y2 = c2
    
    if x1 < x2:
        width = x2 - x1
    elif x1 == x2:
        width = 0
    else:
        width = x1 - x2
    
    if y1 < y2:
         height = y2 - y1
    elif y1 == y2:
         height = 0
    else:
         height = y1 - y2
    
    if height == 0:
        return width
    elif width == 0:
        return height
    
    return math.sqrt((width ** 2) + (height ** 2))

d = calculate_diagonal(c1, c2)
print(d)
```

Comment: Those `if`s are unneccesary. `math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) ** 2) + ((y1 - y2) ** 2))` will give the same result.